# Не перегрузить оператор

Tags: qt, c++

```
class TDigitalIntMatrix
{
public:
    explicit TDigitalIntMatrix(int rows = 2, int columns = 2);
    int matrixCell(int row, int column);    //возвращает значение ячейки массива M[row][column]
    int matrixRowsValue();                  //возвращает количество строк в массиве
    int matrixColumnsValue();               //возвращает количество столбцов в массиве
    TDigitalIntMatrix operator +(TDigitalIntMatrix B);
    ~TDigitalIntMatrix();
private:
    int** M;
    int r, c;
signals:

public slots:

};

TDigitalIntMatrix TDigitalIntMatrix::operator +(TDigitalIntMatrix B)
{
    int columns = B.matrixColumnsValue(),
            rows = B.matrixRowsValue();
    TDigitalIntMatrix Res(rows,columns); //= new TDigitalIntMatrix(rows, columns);
    for(int i=0;i<columns;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<rows;j++) {
            Res.matrixCell(i,j) = this->matrixCell(i,j) + B.matrixCell(i,j);
        }
    }
    return Res;
}
```

На строке `Res.matrixCell(i,j) = this->matrixCell(i,j) + B.matrixCell(i,j);` выдает lvalue required as left operand of assignment. Как избавиться? Или нужно по-другому перегружать?

Comment: Если есть возможность, то лучше использовать готовые библиотеки для работы с матрицами, например, из [Boost::uBLAS][1]. Кроме готовой реализации матриц вы получите массу численных методов для работы с ними.

[1]: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
//...
int buf=0;
int columns = B.matrixColumnsValue(),
            rows = B.matrixRowsValue();  
    TDigitalIntMatrix Res(rows,columns); //= new TDigitalIntMatrix(rows, columns);
    for(int i=0;i<columns;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<rows;j++) {
            buf = this->matrixCell(i,j) + B.matrixCell(i,j);
            Res.setMatrixCell(i, j, buff);
        }    
    }
```

Соответственно вы должны определить метод, устанавливающий значение ячейки.

Answer (score 3):

Плохая передача параметров.

```
//Было:
TDigitalIntMatrix TDigitalIntMatrix::operator +(TDigitalIntMatrix B)

//Стало:
TDigitalIntMatrix& TDigitalIntMatrix::operator +(const TDigitalIntMatrix& B)

// вы пытаетесь присвоить значение тому что само возвращает значение(методу matrixCell).
Res.matrixCell(i,j)

//Наверное вы имели ввиду:
Res.M[i][j]

//Объявление для M:
int** M=new int*[n]; 
for(int i=0; i<=n;i++) 
{ 
  M[i]=new int[m]; 
} 
//m,n размер
```

Это одна из самых плохих реализаций матрицы которую я встречал(я видел их штук 30).

Лучший способ работы с небольшими матрицами фиксированного размера: одномерный массив в стэке и ассемблерные inline функции без циклов, условных переходов и обработки ошибок(её стоит удалить после окончательного тестирования) для работы с ним внутри одного namespace.

Для матриц переменного размера стоит на полную катушку использовать шаблоны.